# C++ Как записать в элемент структуры значение?

Tags: c++, структуры

Нужно записать в `mas_Z[kodS].FIO` значение. Я не понимаю, как это сделать?

```
struct TZap{                  // Структура с которой проходит работа
     char FIO[30];            
     char n_group[5];
     char god_r[4];  
     double o_fizika; 
     double o_matematica; 
     double o_informatica;
     double o_himia;    
     double s_b;        
     } Zap;
int size = sizeof(TZap);             // Размер записи в структуре
char File_Zap[] = "zapisi.dat";      // Файл в котором хранится структура
Fz = fopen(File_Zap,"r+b");          // Получаем поток Fz с данными из файла
D_f = fileno(Fz); 
len = filelength(D_f);               // Получаем размер файла
kol = len/size;                      // Получаем количество строк в файле
char Stroka[30];                     // Буферная переменная для ввода данных
mas_Z = new TZap[kol];               // Объект структуры 

printf("\n F.I.O. - ");              // Вывод сообщения       
scanf("%s", Stroka);                 // Ввод данных и запись в Stroka
&mas_Z[kodS].FIO = Stroka;           // Присвоение элементу записи структуры, значения
```

> 104   24  E:\CProjects\3\main.cpp [Error] lvalue required as left operand
>   of assignment

**UPDATE** 
Если делаю то, что пишет `@AR Hovsepyan`, а именно:

1. Вместо `&mas_Z[kodS].FIO = Stroka;` пишу  `strcpy( mas_Z[kol].FIO, Stroka);`
2. Вместо `mas_Z = new TZap[kol];` пишу `TZap* mas_Z = new TZap[kol];`
3. Вместо `kol = len/size;` пишу `unsigned kol = len/size;`

То никаких изменений в записи структуры я не вижу. Ничего не сохраняется.

Comment: Можно взять `str[n]cpy`

Comment: `@HolyBlackCat`, вы имеете ввиду `strncpy`?

Comment: `strcpy` или `strncpy`, на выбор.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Строку

```
&mas_Z[kodS].FIO = Stroka;
```

Поменяйте на:

```
strcpy( mas_Z[kol].FIO, Stroka);
```

И нужно указать тип обьявленных переменных:

```
TZap* mas_Z = new TZap[kol];
unsigned kol = len/size; 
....
```

Comment: `@AR Hovsepyan`, я обновил текст вопроса, прошу Вас обратить внимание на возникшую ошибку. На данный момент, не совсем понятно, как правильно исправить проблему

Comment: Исправил ошибку. Но проблему так и не решил

Comment: Я же вам писал как нужно